# What does Auth.auth() mean in this code reading data from firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to programming I'm trying to read data from firebase database.
I got this piece of code from Firebase manual, I want to know what does term uid,AUTH.auth() mean here.Is it a variable?I got this code from firebase manual:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
    let user = User(username: username)
    }){ (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: `let userID` creates a constant that stores the value of the current user's Firebase User ID. Then you can use that `userID` to fetch other bits of data from the database like the username.

Answer (score 1):

The `Auth` in this code refers to the Firebase Authentication service. Specifically `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` gets the current user's identification string.

For an explanation of this line of code, and much more about Firebase Authentication, have a look at the [documentation for getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user).

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'Auth'.I got this error when I pasted this piece of code in my file.

Comment: Have you imported `Firebase` or `FIRAuth` (maybe it's `FirebaseAuthUI` I can't remember) to your project?

Comment: See the Firebase documentation on how to set up auth: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start